# Regular Expression is failing in java

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a file name which starts with %payslip%.xml.gpg.

Below are the possible file name example :

```
Taswkly_payslips_Pay27.xml.gpg
exec_payslip.xml.gpg
Cairns_payslips_adv_P27.xml.gpg
```

Could you please help me suggesting the regex for above pattern name.

In the above pattern below things are fixed i.e.

```
*payslip*.xml.gpg.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try `.*payslip.*\\.xml\\.gpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^.*payslip.*\.xml\.gpg$

^            start of the line
.*           any character multiple times
payslip      the string "payslip"
.*           any character multiple times
\.           the "." character
xml          the string "xml"
\.           the "." character
gpg          the string "gpg"
$            end of the line
```

Also don't forget to escape it in java

```
^.*payslip.*\\.xml\\.gpg$
```

[Working example](https://regex101.com/r/H0qrIo/1)

Comment: And of course, you don't need `^` and `$` if you're using the `matches` method of the `String` class.